# Are there things that can be proven with induction that can't be proven with other techniques?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Are there things that can be proven with induction that can't be proven with other techniques?

Or are there cases where direct proof, proof by contradiction, conditional derivation, etc. fail and only induction can generate results?

Comment: There is a Quora question that may appeal to this topic: [If something can be proved by mathematical induction, does it mean that it must be able to be proved through another method without mathematical induction?](https://www.quora.com/If-something-can-be-proved-by-mathematical-induction-does-it-mean-that-it-must-be-able-to-be-proved-through-another-method-without-mathematical-induction)

Comment: hmm, induction itself?

Comment: Yeah! I found the Quora article interesting, especially the appeal to Peano postulates. I wonder what the experts in our community here have to say on this matter.